How to check ArchUnitNet .BeAssignableTo() for generic type?
I am trying to write ArchUnitNet tests cases and unbale to find how to support for generic type assignable to
BeAssignableTo("MediatR.IBaseRequest") -> Does not work with 
Tried below
.BeAssignableTo("MediatR.IBaseRequest");
Expecting to work with any Generic type check with 1..N params ,<T,T> etc.

Using it like this worked:
.BeAssignableTo("MediatR.IBaseRequest<>");  // For single generic type
.BeAssignableTo("MediatR.IBaseRequest<,>"); // For multiple generic types

